# Ubuntu 17.04 : My desktosp pc finds the wireless networks but can't connect to it

Tags: wireless, connection, router

Wifi is not connecting but it scans all the networks. I am using wireless usb adapter. Few months ago, it worked perfectly but after that it didn't work. 
I have tried

```
echo 'options ath9k nohwcrypt=1' | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
```

and

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

commands and also restarted my computer but it didn't work. 
I have done

```
lsusb
```

which has given

```
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter
```

Please help me with the solution. Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6     
I have edited it, please see the results.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need a change to Network Manager; from the terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

Add a new section as follows:

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

After making this change, reboot and let us hear the result.